# Finding all the occurrence of the specific column used by the tables, procedures, functions in the PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

We are altering a **column(notes)** type from **character(9)** to **varchar(50)**. We have thousands of tables, functions, procedures and mviews. I want to identify **all the locations** i.e (tables, functions, procedures, indexes, mviews) where this column is used. Is there any query to find out the locations of the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you have kept to naming convention to have unique column name accross schema, it is doable with selects.

1. tables:

   ```
   select table_name 
   from information_schema.columns 
   where column_name = 'notes';
   ```
2. functions, procedures:

   ```
   select proname 
   from pg_proc 
   where prosrc like '%notes %';
   ```
3. mviews and views:

   ```
   select * from pg_matviews where definition like '%notes%';
   select * from pg_views where definition like '%notes%';
   ```

Of course efficiency of such approach totally depends on how you call your column. And from your provided name **notes**, I think It will be low.

Comment: Thanks @Vao this has saved huge amount of time of mine...especially for the functions, procedures and mviews..

Comment: also read Laurenz answer - I did not check for real dependance for materialized views - only pattern matching approach. For less dependant on naming convention solution check out his queries

Answer (score 1):

That is not easy to solve.

For views an rules you can get the information by querying the `pg_depend` system catalog.

Here is how it works for views and materialized views:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id integer PRIMARY KEY, val text NOT NULL);

CREATE VIEW myview AS
   SELECT count(id) AS c, val FROM mytable GROUP BY val;
```

Now we find out the attribute number for the column `val`:

```
SELECT attnum
FROM pg_attribute
WHERE attrelid = 'mytable'::regclass
  AND attname = 'val';

┌────────┐
│ attnum │
├────────┤
│      2 │
└────────┘
(1 row)
```

Now we can find out which views depend on the column:

```
SELECT ev_class::regclass
FROM pg_depend d
   JOIN pg_rewrite r
      ON d.objid = r.oid
WHERE d.refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass
  AND d.refobjid = 'mytable'::regclass
  AND d.refobjsubid = 2
  AND r.rulename = '_RETURN';

┌──────────┐
│ ev_class │
├──────────┤
│ myview   │
└──────────┘
(1 row)
```

The real problem arises with functions.

The function body is stored as a string in the `prosrc` attribute of `pg_proc`, but the contents are only parsed by the language handler at runtime and there are no dependencies stored in `pg_depend`.

So the best you can do is something like

```
SELECT proname
FROM pg_proc
WHERE prosrc ILIKE '%val%';
```

But that may turn up a lot of false positives, and you'd have to go through the code yourself to figure out if your column is referenced or not.